# How to make short name to an Array property

Tags: javascript, function-prototypes

I often have typos in typing word "length" and would like to make a short name to this property. For example "len"

I can easily make an Array method:

```
Array.prototype.len = function(){ return this.length }
```

but then i should call [1,2,3].len() with brackets...
But how to make a property? (and call it with [1,2,3].len )

I've tried something like this:

```
Array.prototype.len = (function(arr) {return arr.length})(this)
```

but **this** isn't seen in such way

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't extend native prototypes. You may define `Array.len = ...` and call `Array.len([1,2,3])` though

Comment: So a function, callable as a property? You might want to look at getters, but IE doesn't support it.

Comment: yeah, I see, __ defineGetter __ would help me, but IE doesn't support it =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `getter` like this:

```
Array.prototype.__defineGetter__("len", function() {
    return this.length;
});

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.len // 3
```

(Please note: as mentioned in the comments above, it's usually a bad idea to modify the `prototype` of a native object. Also note that browser support for JavaScript getters/setters is probably sketchy.)